# Elementary OS (Linux) documentation

Tags: linux, terminal, operating-system, documentation

I'm having my first contact with the Linux terminal, and I'm looking for some-kind of manual or command list.

I tried:  `-h or -help command`
*but is a short information only about the command*

I tried:  `-man command`
*but is a information only about a specific command*

Please help me find more information about the commands.

Comment: Have a try with the `apropos` command: `man apropos`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the elementary documentation that should let you get going:

Your terminal is called `bash`, commands to look and move around are `ls`, `cd`, `pwd`. Command to see the file contents is `less`, command to edit the file is `vi`. To run the command in foreground just type it, to do the same in the background add ampersand `&` to the command line. To see what's running (launched from the same terminal) type `jobs`. To send the foreground job to background type `^Z` and then `bg`. To bring a background job back to foreground type `fg %x` where `x` is a numeric ID of the job returned by `jobs` command. To kill a job gracefully type `kill %x`, to kill hard -- `kill -9 %x`.

To learn about command use `man` to learn about running process use `pstack` and `strace`.

To learn about network use `ifconfig` and `netstat`.

Have a look at [tldp.org](http://tldp.org), in particular its [Bash tutorial for beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), they are awesome.

Welcome to the world of perfect interfaces!

Comment: The OP did not ask if someone could try to write a list of commands, but for a documentation.

Comment: What I pasted IS an elementary documentation. It is enough to not get lost. And tldp.org is the next step to take. What exactly have you disliked?

Comment: Apart from the mentioning of "tldp.org" which might be a helpful comment this does not really help the OP. So now he knows about a few commands names, but you did not give him any real means to find out more. this is like telling a kid asking how learning works to learn a poem and thus see that it can learn something.

Comment: Why don't you post your own answer?

Comment: What does my own answer have to do with this? Sorry if I offended you. I certainly did not mean any personal insult. And frankly I see absolutely no reason for interpreting my comment that way.

Comment: If you answer yourself you will help the OP and show me how the good answer should look like - win/win.